# Alternar entre modais

Tags: javascript, html

Quero fazer um modal onde posso visualizar o cadastro e se eu clicar para Editar subir o outro modal, assim alternando entre os formulários.

**HTML com modal:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="visualizar">
        <form>
           Exemplo
           <button type="button" class="btn-editar">Editar</button>
        </form>
       </div>

       <div class="form-edita">
         <form>Exemplo2
          <button type="button" class="btn-canc-edit" >Cancelar Edição</button>
         </form>
       </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
$('.btn-editar').on("click", function () {
  $('.form').slideToggle();
  $('.visualizar').slideToggle();
});
$('.btn-canc-edit').on("click", function () {
  $('.visualizar').slideToggle();
  $('.form').slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
.visualizar {
    display: block;
}

.form-edita {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Quando eu clico para aparecer o de Editar, ele aparece, mas não fica em cima do de visualizar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem uma técnica fácil para isso:

Apague o seu script e CSS e tente com este código:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.form-edita').hide();
        $('.btn-editar').click(function(){
            $('.visualizar').hide();
            $('.form-edita').show();
        });
        $('.btn-canc-edit').click(function(){
            $('.form-edita').hide();
            $('.visualizar').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Além disso,** você pode criar outro modal, por exemplo, deixa este como #modal_visualizar e cria um como #modal_editar.

Desta maneira, quando o usuário clicar no botão .btn-editar que está no #modal_visualizar, o mesmo irá se esconder e irá exibir o #modal_editar. Dentro do #modal_editar, você pode criar um botão para retornar ao modal de visualização.

Então ficaria assim:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.btn-editar').click(function(){
            $('#modal_visualizar').modal("hide");
            $('#modal_editar').modal("show");
        });
        $('.btn-canc-edit').click(function(){ // Este botão ficará no #modal_editar
            $('#modal_editar').modal("hide");
            $('#modal_visualizar').modal("show");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Bom, eu particularmente faria a segunda opção, pois terá um efeito muito mais agradável para o usuário final.

Espero ter te ajudado :)

Answer (score 0):

você pode fazer o seguinte, substituir a função toogle() por atacar direto o css. Sendo assim você altera o atributo "display" da classe CSS "visualizar" e editar. mostrando e ocultando os formulários.
Editei seu código java script, veja se isso ajuda.

```
<script>
$('.btn-editar').on("click", function () {
  $('.visualizar').css("display","none");
  $('.form-edita').css("display","block");
});
$('.btn-canc-edit').on("click", function () {
  $('.form-edita').css("display","none");

});
</script>
```